# Angular date pipe parsing error "222-02-01" in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I have just run into a problem with the angular date pipe where I need to format the display of dates returned from an API. 99% of the time this works without any problem as the format of the date is valid. However, I encountered a situation in which chrome doesn't throw an error but firefox does:

In the situation where i pass the date directly from the API response to my date pipe i get the following:

> InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "222-02-01" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

In the situation where i attempt to let the browser convert the response to a date and then pass into the pipe using `new Date()` i get

> Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

The date in question is `222-02-01` which I believe firefox is then converting to the string of "Invalid Date" which angular's date pipe understandably cannot parse. But, it is fine with `0222-02-1` value.

I'm hoping someone with a greater understanding of javascript dates could explain how they work in different browsers.

Also if there is a solution to either gracefully let the angular pipe error and fall back to the string representation or parse the date with an alternative method before passing it to the angular date pipe

Comment: `"222-02-01"` is **not** a date. I can't even guess what date that could possibly be. I do not understand why you're asking a question about the date pipe here? Seems like you're ignoring the very obvious problem of using a bad API.

Comment: Right, I agree with @Reactgular. I'd look into addressing why your API is giving clearly incorrect dates before worrying about why your browsers are handling the incorrect date differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the base form is: YYYY-MM-DD. But it exists other as well;
https://javascript.info/date
The API should not send the date in that format. I assume its send JSON data. 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm